# Displaying 3 image links side by side

Tags: html, css

I have on my website 3 images that I'm trying to display side by side. They way I have researched and learned and read has put them vertical, stacking on top of each other. This is not what I'm looking for.

My question is, what kind of html or css am I missing to be able to do this?

My css:

```
#imagestyle {
width:100%;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
}
span {
display:inline-block;
margin:5px;
}
```

My html:

```
<div id="imagestyle">
<span><a href="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Kayak-Whitewater.jpg"><img alt="Kayak Whitewater rafting" src="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Kayak-Whitewater-150x150.jpg" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<p>Kayak</p>
</span>
<span><a href="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Raft-Whitewater.jpg"><img alt="Rafting Whitewater" src="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Raft-Whitewater-150x150.jpg" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<p>Inflatable Raft</p>
</span>
<span><a href="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Paddleboard-Whitewater.jpg"><img alt="Paddleboard Whitewater Rafting" src="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Paddleboard-Whitewater-150x150.jpg" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<p>Paddleboard</p>
</span>
</div>
```

I can't figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, http://www.dutchjohnresort.com/rafting/ is the website if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: All of the code I put in here was copy pasted from my site. I don't know how it's different. Thank you for the answers tho. I will work on cleanup and see if that helps.

Comment: The above code works like you want I believe: http://jsfiddle.net/KT3em/. Since you are setting the container element to `width : 100%` you should check the container's parent element to make sure it's not forcing a narrow layout.

Comment: oooo boy, I took a look at your source and your HTML structure is bogus which is your whole issue. Just clean-up your HTML. You have `<br />` tags between `<span />` tags which will force new lines... You also have tags that are improperly nested. This makes browsers render your HTML differently than you expect.

Comment: In response to your edit. If you are using a content management system, that could be your issue. WYSISYG editors make assumptions and update your HTML a lot of the time. E.g. maybe the `<br />` tags are added because of a WYSISYG editor.

Comment: I am using wordpress. So yes a cms. Is there a way I can clean that up? Or is that from my theme/plugins/etc.?

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you what specifically to do for WordPress. But you can now search Google (or whatever) for "wordpress adding HTML to my content" or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted on your question doesn't match the code on your site:

[image: differences]

If you use the code you posted, it will work perfectly as @Jasper showed up on the jsfiddler demo

Comment: This is definately the correct answer. The OP's HTML on the actual site is way different than what he posted. The OP just needs to paste the code here into the site and it'll work.

Comment: @Jasper I had to check his site since I got the same result as you by using the `HTML markup` on jsfiddle, 2 demos can't be that wrong/good :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine, on your website you have all 3 images in one `<span>` tag which is causing them to be treated as one `inline-block`. 
Replace the code on your live site with:

```
<div id="imagestyle">
<span><a href="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Kayak-Whitewater.jpg"><img alt="Kayak Whitewater rafting" src="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Kayak-Whitewater-150x150.jpg" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<p>Kayak</p>
</span>
<span><a href="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Raft-Whitewater.jpg"><img alt="Rafting Whitewater" src="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Raft-Whitewater-150x150.jpg" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<p>Inflatable Raft</p>
</span>
<span><a href="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Paddleboard-Whitewater.jpg"><img alt="Paddleboard Whitewater Rafting" src="http://dutchjohnresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Paddleboard-Whitewater-150x150.jpg" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<p>Paddleboard</p>
</span>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you are describing the ones which are on the website that aren't in his code above they have no content in them and no structural purpose.

Comment: A DOM inspector will show only one `<span />` tag but if you look at the source of the site you'll notice this is just because there are improperly nested HTML tags. Browsers do not render some of the improperly nested tags so the DOM inspector kind of miss-leads us in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Try span `{float: left}` . Say if works

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.